# Where is user agent stylesheet located and how can I disable it?

Tags: sass

I have a link where I want to set the `text-decoration` to `none`.
The problem is that when I change it in my **SCSS** file it doesn't change.

How can I disable or override the User Agent Stylesheet?

I tried to inspect the webpage, but it just shows me some styles (that overrides my code) in the User Agent Stylesheet.

This is my code:

```
.site-name {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1.2vw);
  color: white;
}
```

..and this is the User Agent Stylesheet's code:

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

I expect the link to be without underline and white, but how can I override it.

Comment: The User Agent Stylesheet is the browsers default styles.  It gives things like headings a default font-size and paragraphs a default margin. It will not contain a style definition for a class named `.site-name` - or any classes for that matter. What makes you think that the styles are coming from the User Agent Stylesheet?

Comment: You can override other styles with yours using [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)